# Geoserver WFS request resultType=hits

Tags: geoserver, wfs, json, xml, request

I try get number of features through WFS request:

```
    $.ajax('http://x.x.x.x/geoserver/wfs',{
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typeName: 'workspace:layer',
                outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
                srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
                resultType: 'hits',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326'
                },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback:'parseResponse',
            jsonp:'format_options'
    }).then(function(response) {
    var result = parserJSON.readFeatures(response);
    });
```

But I get Uncaught SyntaxError. Response is not JSONP.

response:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
    xmlns:tiger="http://www.census.gov" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
    xmlns:baikalgeol="http://www.geol.irk.ru/baikalgeol"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberOfFeatures="35"
    timeStamp="2016-10-07T02:38:43.015Z"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"/>
```

As see server return numberOfFeatures="35".

I changed outputFormat on 'GML3' and parseGML3 (openlayers format). But it did not help.

How wrap response in json or read this xml without rest?

Comment: GeoServer is indeed returning the requests with &resulltype=hits as GML even if some other outputformat is defined http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&outputformat=application/json&resulttype=hits.  Perhaps that's because all outputformats, like zipped shapefile, can't present the result of such query. The GML output contains the information that you need, is your problem in parsing?

Comment: Problem in reciving xml. I can not even bring it to the console.

Comment: Ajax error: AJAX: [object Object] | parsererror | Error: parseResponse was not called NaN

Answer (score 2):

From the look of [`HitsOutputFormat`](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wfs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wfs/response/HitsOutputFormat.java) GeoServer only returns hits in `text/xml` format.

If you would like to [modify this code and submit a pull request](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) I'm sure the developers would review it favourably. Please also read the [note](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer) on resourcing feature requests and enhancements.

Comment: Is there a GitHub Issue tracking this?

Comment: We use jjra to track issues - https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/issues/